# How to fetch objects in joins?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

This is my schema :

```
Mention.rb

belongs_to :user


create_table "mentions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id",          limit: 4
  t.integer  "mentionable_id",   limit: 4
  t.string   "mentionable_type", limit: 191
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.datetime "deleted_at"
end
```

User.rb

```
No Association.
```

Query:

```
mentions = Mention.joins(:user).where(mentions: {mentionable_type: 'Comment', mentionable_id: @comments_ids}).select('users.*, mentions.mentionable_id AS comment_id').group_by(&:comment_id)
```

Output :

```
=> {155=>
  [#<Mention:0x00007ff51a309de8 id: 110, created_at: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 10:19:46 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 10:19:46 UTC +00:00, deleted_at: nil>,
   #<Mention:0x00007ff51a3092f8 id: 112, created_at: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 10:19:46 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 10:19:46 UTC +00:00, deleted_at: nil>],
 156=>[#<Mention:0x00007ff51a3098e8 id: 111, created_at: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 10:19:46 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 10:19:46 UTC +00:00, deleted_at: nil>]}
```

`id:110` that is here in the output is of `user` and `115` is `mentionable_id`.

How can I get complete user object with group_by mentionable_id ?

Expected:

```
=> {155=>
      [#<User:0x00007ff51a309de8 id: 110, name: "abc", email: 'xyz@mail.com', deleted_at: nil>,
      #<User:0x00007ff51a3092f8 id: 112, name: "abc", email: 'xyz@mail.com', deleted_at: nil>],
 156=>[#<User:0x00007ff51a3098e8 id: 111, name: "abc", email: 'xyz@mail.com', deleted_at: nil>]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query through `User`:

```
User.joins(:mentions)
    .where(mentions: { mentionable_type: 'Comment', mentionable_id: @comments_ids })
    .select('users.*, mentions.mentionable_id AS comment_id')
    .group_by(&:comment_id)
```